# Old services vs Background services vs Foreground services

Tags: android, kotlin, service, foreground-service

In Kotlin android there were services, which work for older android versions, then there are background and foreground services. What are the differences?
If I created an app with an old service will it work on new phones?
I use my service for stopper working in the background with notification, maybe I should use something else?

Answer (score 0):

This stackoverflow link should answer your question
[Timer in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741477/timer-in-background/19741507)

You can also use this approach by creating a CountDownTimer extending a Service Class. You can reuse it at multiple instances.
[Android count down timer in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123231/android-count-down-timer-in-background)